# React Router have to reload page to change url

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

I´m setting up a website with React. My problem is that I have to refresh the page in order to come to the correct url. I`m quite new to React so sorry if this question is easy.

Comment: Are you using the [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)? It uses the HTML5 history API to update the UI based on the URL without needing a page refresh.

Comment: Can you show us your code ? It's difficult to give you a answer without seeing more oy your app.

Comment: Are you using plain links or the provided Link component?

Comment: Please share the code sample